# CSS: Background color to text size

Tags: css

I'm would like to color the background of a text but only to it's size.

Images are better than a thousand words, here is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

And this is what I am achieving

[image]

I don't want to do this programmatically, I would like the background to adapt to the text ( because it may be dynamic )

Is there anyway to do this without using javascript?

Update (HTML):

```
<div class="team-member-teaser-name">OSCAR</div>
```

CSS

```
.team-member-teaser-name
{
    color: #4fb4d0;
    background: #135364;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

**Update** (Solved, based on @BoldClock answer):

```
.team-member-teaser-name
{
    color: #4FB4D0;
    background: #135364;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    font-size: 10px;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 9px;
    clear: both;
}
```

I don't really understand how clear works, but is required to achieve the results on the image.

Comment: Can you include your HTML - using background-color in CSS will fill the containing element

Comment: That seems like your span / label / element has a fixed width associated with it. What does your markup / CSS currently look like?

Comment: Can you give a sample of the HTML surrounding the text you wish to add the style to?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to apply the background color to an inline element. If the text is in a block element, you need to wrap the text in an inline child of the block element (assuming it's not feasible to put `display: inline` on the block element). And if you can't edit the HTML, you will have to do it within a script.

Answer (score 7):

You could wrap your text in a span like this:

```
<p><span class="highlight">OSCAR</span></p>
```

and then, depending on you current css you could style it like this:

```
.highlight{
    background-color: blue; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `background` property to define a background color. For eg,

```
<a href="#">oscar</a>

a{ background:#ff0000; }
```

If you have inline elements such as a `<span />` or `<a />` you can add `display:block` to the styles if you want to define a height and width on the element. Additionally, you can also define a padding on the element if you want to control the spacing area around the text to give your text some breathing room.

Comment: Unfortunately, adding `display: block` makes the background color take up the full horizontal extent of the block rather than just the size of the text and it's padding.